# importing less files to webstorm without explicit "@import"

Tags: import, less, webstorm

Can webstorm know that less files exist in the project without using "@import"? a way of reducing the use of "@import"! or at least, to import the file without giving it the full path?

Answer (score 1):

In WebStorm, variables and mixins in LESS are resolved and completed in the following way:

1. If element can be resolved to declaration from current file or from
   explicitly imported files, then it is resolved to it without any
   warnings.
2. If element can't be found in current file or files
       available by explicit imports, but similar declaration is found in
       one of project .less files, then it is resolved just by name.
       Resolved element is marked with a  weak-warning inspection 'Resolved
       by name only'.

Completion list for variables and mixins includes all variables/mixins from all files in project. Elements defined in current file or in explicitly imported files are placed on the top of completion list and have bold font. Variables/mixins from other files are marked with 'implicitly imported'-hint.

as for import paths, please see comments in [WEB-7452](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7452) for possible workarounds

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While searching I found this plugin:
https://github.com/just-boris/less-plugin-glob
what do you think of it?